# WordPress Multisite directory nginx config

Tags: wordpress, nginx, subdirectory, multisite

I am trying to setup WordPress Multisite with subdirectories behind nginx.

Initially my WordPress was hosted at `https://example.com/wordpress`, and now I am moving it to Multisite.

`wp-config.php` seems fine:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );

define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'example.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/wordpress/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1); `
```

My `nginx.conf` is:

```
server { 
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    root /var/www/; # wordpress is at /var/www/wordpress, All wp files are in this wordpress folder
    index index.php;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    recursive_error_pages on;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    # Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
    rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

    # Pass uploaded files to wp-includes/ms-files.php.
    rewrite /files/$ /wordpress/index.php last;

    if ($uri !~ wp-content/plugins) {
        rewrite /files/(.+)$ /wordpress/wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 last;
    }

    # Rewrite multisite '.../wp-.*' and '.../*.php'.
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite_log on;
        rewrite ^/(/[^/]+)?(/wp-.*) wordpress/$2 last;
        rewrite ^/(/[^/]+)?(/.*\.php) wordpress/$2 last;

        # rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/wp-.*) $1 last;
        # rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/.*\.php)$ $1 last;
    }

    location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        set $skip_cache 0;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;

        if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml") {
            set $skip_cache 1;
        }

        fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
        fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
        fastcgi_cache microcache;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 5m;
    }
}
```

I create a website now called "Site2": `https://example.com/wordpress/site2`

But the this site does not load the page properly. When I view
`https://example.com/wordpress/site2/wp-admin/` I get the error:

> This webpage has a redirect loop.

An immediate help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, if you want your sites to run as

https://example.com/site1

https://example.com/site2

here is what you can do,

go to network setup>sites
change the site2 address from /wordpress/site2 to /site2

Also you need to fix, nginx config as follows

```
# rewrite ^/(/[^/]+)?(/wp-.*) wordpress/$2 last;
# rewrite ^/(/[^/]+)?(/.*\.php) wordpress/$2 last;

 rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/wp-.*) /wordpress$1 last;
 rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/.*\.php)$ /wordpress$1 last;
```

That is you need to use your uncommented code, with some fix